# Optimize Postgresql query filtered by datetime field greather than

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 2M of rows, this table is defined with a date field containing insert datetime (default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

I would like to be able to get all the row with date > X as fast as possible.

Is there a way to optimize the query so that whenever a date is not matching the condition, the queryset is returned (given the fact that date are naturally ordered from the highest to the lowest - same as pk) so no need to assess previous inserts.

I'm not sure if index could help me here

Thank you for your help

Comment: ....yes, an index would normally be assumed to help (especially if the condition is a fairly small sample of the table).  Why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: Why do you think index not help you? it's obvious index will make your query data faster.. And 2m row are still not many with now great advanced technology in `rdbms`..

Comment: Actually, I'm neither saying index won't help nor 2M row is a lot. Instead I'm looking for the most optimized query to get my data as fast as possible. I'm not familiar at all with indexes; can you help me to set up the right one then?